# Location of vagrant and Vagrantfile within git repository

Tags: node.js, git, vagrant

I want to have a single git repository for a node.js project that contains both the source code as well as Vagrant provisioning details. Where should the vagrant folder and accompanying Vagrantfile be located within the main (node.js) repository to comply with best practice and have the least filesystem mapping challenges?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found that the best location for the Vagrantfile within a git project is in the very root. That way by default the entire repository will be mounted inside the Vagrant VM in /vagrant.